# How do I take a variable in C# and store it in a Database?

Tags: c#, database, console-application

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {            
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int hatNum;
            string hatInput;
            Console.WriteLine("How many Hats? ");
            hatInput = Console.ReadLine();               
        }
    }
}
```

I want to take user input and store it as a variable, but then save it to a database. I've been googling around for a while for exactly how to do this.

Aside from the code listed, I added a Service-Based Database to the project.

[image]

But maybe I'm bad at searching but I have yet to find out how to take a value from a variable and add it to a database.

Or maybe I'm doing it wrong and there's some other less complicated way to save information from variables?

Comment: Looks like you're at the *very* beginning of figuring this out. Don't think of it as storing variables, but as storing values. Google 'Insert statements' for the exact kind of DB you will be using. The values you *insert* come from your variables. Your tables will have to exist already. There are several steps in the process of communicating with the DB and then adding data to it, or getting data from it.

Comment: @wazz I found a way to insert values. 
INSERT INTO Hats (Id, hatNumbers)
VALUES (1, 4)

I haven't found how to connect this to the program yet. Any particular search I should try for that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should create your DataBase and Your Tables (for your convenience using sql managment studio) then just use insert statement to put the value of your Variable into DB . the insert statement is be like :

```
public string ConnString = "Your Connection String";
      

   public void InsertReq(HatVal)
   {
       try
       {
          
           SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
           string insertReq =
               "INSERT into dbo.Hats (HatNumber) VALUES (@HatNumber)";

           SqlCommand queryInsertReq = new SqlCommand(insertReq);
           queryInsertReq.Connection = openCon;

           queryInsertReq.Parameters.Add("@HatNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HatVal;
           
           openCon.Open();
           queryInsertReq.ExecuteNonQuery();
           openCon.Close();
           
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Logger.Log.Error("Inserting In Db Failed , " + ex.Message);
       }
   }
```